# Free software to define mouse hotspots, like "point to upper left -- display off"?

Tags: gratis, open-source, windows-7, mouse

The title says it all -- I'd like to define mouse hotspots which, when pointed to, will, possibly after a definable delay, perform a definable action, like going to the lockscreen, blanking the display, or similar stuff.

Is there a utility that implements this as a system-wide desktop mouse monitor?

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://superuser.com/questions/522187/how-do-i-set-a-hot-corner-in-windows-7 -- lol

Comment: If it weren't on another site, it indeed would be a duplicate. Feel free to [answer your own question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) then :)

Comment: Will do as soon as I constructed a solution based on one of the packages described in the "dupe"